# UPDATE syntax that works in major databases

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server, oracle, ansi-sql

I want to update a table (`target`) based on the values present in another table (`source`). But I am looking for a syntax that will work in 4 major databases - Oracle, MS SQL Server, PostgreSQL, MySQL.

So far, I am not able to find such a uniform syntax. Have I missed such syntax or there is really no such syntax?

## Oracle

```
UPDATE target t
SET (t.col1, t.col2) = (SELECT s.col1, s.col2 
                       FROM source s 
                       WHERE s.key = t.key)
```

## MS SQL Server / PostgreSQL

```
UPDATE target t
SET t.col1 = s.col1, t.col2 = s.col2
FROM source s
WHERE t.key=s.key
```

## MySQL

```
UPDATE target, source 
SET t.col1=s.col1, t.col2=s.col2
WHERE s.key=t.key
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is inefficient, but the ANSI SQL Standard way to do this is:

```
UPDATE target
SET col1 = (SELECT s.col1
           FROM source s 
           WHERE s.key = target.key),
    col2 = (SELECT s.col2 
           FROM source s 
           WHERE s.key = target.key);
```

This does not mean to say it will work in every RDBMS (e.g. I don't think it would work in Access), but it does work in the 4 you have listed.

I would personally value performance over portability every day of the week so I would not use this syntax. I would be inclined to use a use a stored-procedure, with a common name, but differing syntax for each RDBMS.

**UPDATE**

Actually, the method you have shown for Oracle using row value constructors is also allowed by the ANSI SQL Standard:

```
UPDATE target
SET (t.col1, t.col2) = (SELECT s.col1, s.col2 
                       FROM source s 
                       WHERE s.key = t.key);
```

Unfortunately, as mentioned above, just because it is in the ANSI Standards it does not mean that it works across platforms.

Comment: Not necessarily that inefficient

Comment: @Ben Not necessarily, but in the given example it would require reading from the source twice, as opposed to once. I would consider this inefficient. If the update was 5 columns, it would require 5 times as many reads, if instead of a simple table lookup, the sub-query was more complicated, then even more work is being repeated.

Comment: My testing (SQL Server) on 100million rows suggests that when updating the whole table, if there is a clustered index there is a 20% to 40% penalty for each additional column, where the tables are in-memory (which is hopefully all the time). Which is definitely significant. So I guess it is a trade-off between maintenance headache of maintaining multiple queries vs. how important the peformance is.

Answer (score 2):

ANSI update syntax (it should work in DBMS that you listed):

```
update t1 
    set col1 = (
                select col1 
                from t2 
                where t1.key = t2.key
              ),
    set col2 = (
                select col2 
                from t2 
                where t1.key = t2.key
              )
```